# julia struct inner constructor optional type specification

Tags: struct, types, constructor, julia

Consider the following struct:

```
struct MyType1{T}
    data::T
end
```

It can be instantiated in two ways:

```
println(MyType1(5))                 # MyType1{Int64}(5)
println(MyType1{Int}(5))            # MyType1{Int64}(5)
```

When I define something similar with inner constructor:

```
struct MyType2{T}
    data::T
    MyType2(x::T) where T = new{T}(x)
end

struct MyType3{T}
    data::T
    MyType3{T}(x::T) where T = new{T}(x)
end
```

I can instantiate them only in one way:

```
println(MyType2(5))                 # MyType2{Int64}(5)
println(MyType2{Int}(5))            # MethodError

println(MyType3(5))                 # MethodError
println(MyType3{Int}(5))            # MyType3{Int64}(5)
```

How can I make type specification in inner constructor optional (make `MyType2` and `MyType3` not to throw `MethodError` in the example above)?

*julia version 1.4.1*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just provide an additional constructor:

```
struct MyType4{T}
   data::T
   MyType4{T}(x::T) where T = new{T}(x)
end

MyType4(x::T) where T = MyType4{T}(x)
```

Test

```
julia> MyType4{Int}(5)
MyType4{Int64}(5)

julia> MyType4(5)
MyType4{Int64}(5)
```